# Angular 2 - Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: angularjs, json, angular, laravel-5

i'am trying to make a post request to my RESTful api on Laravel 5.2. But in the console appear this:

> "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Here is the code:

```
private post(post: Post): Promise<Post> {
    let headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return this.http
               .post(this.url+'courses', JSON.stringify(post ||  null), {headers: headers})
               .toPromise()
               .then(res => res.json().data)
               .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Someone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Your JSON isn't JSON (you're probably receiving an HTML file containing an error message.)  Check the contents of `res`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at Object.parse (native) (AngularJS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948990/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0-at-object-parse-native)

Comment: @DanielBeck This is "res content":  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />