# Angular4 http.post To JSON Or PHP

Tags: angular

## What I'm Using:

Angular 4 QuickStart seed using Node and NPM.

## Goal:

To post data to a .json file. i.e. Add a new person to an array inside people.json

## Issue:

When I use the http.post method to post data to a .json file, I get a 404 error saying that the file.json is not found.

If I use http.get, it finds and retrieves the data just fine. The URL path that I pass in is exactly the same.

## Code:

#### people.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Person} from './person';

@Injectable()
export class PeopleService
{
    private testUrl = './data/people.json';
    constructor(private http: Http) {}
    Create(param: any): Observable<Person> 
    {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(this.testUrl, body, options)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    /*
       HELPER/ERROR
    */
    private extractData(res: Response)
    {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || { };
    }

    private handleError (error: Response | any) 
    {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) 
        {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else 
        {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

#### person-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { Person} from './person';
import { PeopleService } from './people.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'person-detail',
    templateUrl: './person-detail.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./person-detail.component.css']
})
export class PersonDetailComponent implements OnInit
{
    @Input() person: Person;
    errorMessage: string;

    ngOnInit(): void{}

    constructor(
        private peopleService: PeopleService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private location: Location
    ){}

    Add()
    {
        this.peopleService.Create(this.person).subscribe(/*person
=> person = this.person, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error*/);
    }
}
```

## Edit:

Based on the comments about needing a server-side API to Post to, I've written a tiny test.php file and I'm getting an "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 error"

After reading this post, [SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at Object.parse (native) (AngularJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948990/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0-at-object-parse-native), it sounds like I'm getting an html error before my json, causing the unexpected token in JSON, but I don't know what error I might be getting as my php terminal only says "PHP Notice: Array to string conversion in C:..."

#### people.service.ts (adjusted lines only)

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

private testUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/test.php';

Create(param: any): Observable<Person> 
{
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let urlParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlParams.append('method', 'add');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, search: urlParams 
    });

    return this.http.post(this.testUrl, param, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

#### test.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-type");

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
//$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "Request method: ".$method;
echo "<br>";
//echo "Request: ".$request;
echo "<br>";
echo "Request input: ".$input;

?>
```

PHP is running on the PHP built-in web server with this command entered from the location of test.php in the project folder:

```
php -S localhost:8080 test.php
```

Comment: why are you posting to a json file? the error means that this file doesn't exist or cannot be handled by a post request. Anyway, if your json file is not behind an API, this should not work at all.

Comment: I don't understand your downvote, please explain. Also, I haven't built a php api yet so I'm using json to test the functions without a server. Following the Tour of Heroes tutorial, the next step was to get data from .json file. I've done that, so I tried to post data to it as my next step. Why should it not work?

Comment: You cannot just post to a file, you have to post to a service that is waiting for the post request. Build the API you mentioned and post to that.

Comment: So, the reason I can't post to a file is because it has to be on the server? I thought an api is just a way to hide the functionality from the user, but still uses methods to post to a file. However, with what you just said it seems like it must be on the server, so for a php api I would post to php, and php would then add the decoded json data to file. Is this more or less the right understanding?

Comment: @slanden Well, I'd assume you would post to put something in the DB and no "file" when using api. But it's true, you cannot post to a static file in your project. There is no possibility.

Comment: @AJT_82 Yes, I would post to a DB but since I ran into the problem with the file I wanted to know how to do it just for knowledge sake. But if it's not even possible, that's just as good a resolution to the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's unfortunately not possible to post to a static file. So yes, you are better off setting up the api! Good luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

## Issue 1) http.post to json:

- posting data directly to json is **not possible**. Thanks to R. Richards and AJT_82 for clearing this up for me.

## Issue 2) http.post to php:

- > Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

In this case, this error was caused by my test.php file. not returning proper json. Changing the echo statement to echo a json object resolves the issue.

#### In Detail:

In my PeopleService, the `post()` method is called without error, but the following `map()` method is where the error happens. I pass in a custom function with a default parameter of a `Response` object, `extractData(res: Response)`. This function takes in the Response object of the http request, which is expecting json:

#### people.service.ts

```
Create(param: any): Observable<Person> 
{
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.testUrl, body, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}

/*
   HELPER/ERROR
*/
private extractData(res: Response)
{
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
}
```

However, in my test.php file I was not returning json, I was returning echo statements of html tags (and php variables) which start with '<', hence the unexpected token.

#### test.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-type");

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
//$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));
//$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

echo "<br>";  // this is where the unexpected token '<' comes from
echo "Request method: ".$method;   
?>
```

I couldn't just delete the echo statements, because that returns a new error stating an "unexpected end of JSON input". So, I got rid of this error by changing the echo statement to echo a syntactically correct json object.

#### new test.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-type");

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
//$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));
//$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
$myObj->data = "data";

echo json_encode($myObj);
?>
```

I do not yet understand why the map() method and returning a json object from php is required, but that's how I got around this issue.

*Please note the php headers are temporary for local testing and should not remain in a production php api for security reasons.